# TOSCA Desktop XScan is not recognizing any properties, can't select anything

Tags: tosca

Just installed TOSCA and using the free trial version.

I do not know why when I do desktop scan for my internet explorer browser, it doesn't scan/recognize any of the properties. (Please see picture)

[image]

My resolution and browser is set to 100% already as recommended.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Couple of things to check -
1. Move the Filtered Item slider on the toolbar to All and see if anything appears in the scan
2. Check the source of the web page via Dev Tools of browser and see if the web page have any HTML controls or just a big container element (because I already see a iframe element on the screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what went wrong - I tried this with my copy and I get the exact same result if I choose UIA to scan the window. Be sure that you use Html - you can select that when you are in the "Select Application" dialog, right after you start the scan. 
When you right click the Internet Explorer there, you get a drop down where you can select this:

[image]